# Mysql & codeigniter load very slow

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I've developed webshop project but I have issue with slow query response.
I'm using codeigniter framework and I am using `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);`

This is what I get as a query:

```
SELECT `products`.`id`, `products`.`image`, `products`.`onsale`, `products`.`folder`, `products`.`productRating`, `products`.`pro_vat`, `products`.`pro_code`, `products`.`quantity`, `products`.`shop_categorie`, `products_translations`.`title`, `products_translations`.`price`, `products_translations`.`pdv`, `products_translations`.`old_price`, `products_translations`.`description`, `products_translations`.`shortdescription`, `products`.`url`, `brands`.`image` as `bimage`
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `products_translations` ON `products_translations`.`for_id` = `products`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `brands` ON `brands`.`id` = `products`.`brand_id`
ORDER BY `position` ASC
LIMIT 20
```

and it takes more than 6 seconds to load it.
Just to mention, I have around 2.500 items in product table.

Is it possible to reduce loading time somehow?

Comment: did you set indexes correctly? and try without order by to see if the bottleneck lies there

Comment: What do you mean? Query works as it should, the problem is with loading time

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Let me check what's that

Comment: Yea, I've set "primary key" on "id" columns for all tables (products, products_translations, brands)

Comment: Yea, you are on the right path. When I removed order by, it reduced it on 0.04s. So this is the trick. So I should avoid using order by

Comment: have you set any index for position?

Answer (score 0):

I would also say that you should check the indexes first.
Altough as I can see you are using IDs only in your where clauses. If you set the primary key in proper way then they should not be a problem.

Have you checked your server resources?

If there is no problem with your server and indexes then you should start using views in your database to avoid 'left joins' every time when you run a query.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer and explain why `start using views in your database to avoid 'left joins' every time when you run a query` will help to reduce the execution time of the query?